# PowerShell: **reading** input from the keyboard AND **redirecting output** to a variable/file

Tags: powershell, script, redirection, input, stdout

Sorry if my question is trivial; I'm a beginner with PowerShell.

My program (plink) is expecting for an answer from the keyboard and will return some output.
Is it possible to redirect the *output* to a *variable/file*?

#### Details:

<sub>(I am assigning the command, itself, to a variable,
for convenience.)</sub>

**Without output redirection — Console output is OK:**

```
PS C:\Users\user> $mycmd="plink -v -ssh -l $user $myserver vncserver -list"
PS C:\Users\user> invoke-expression $mycmd
user@server's password:
TigerVNC server sessions:
X DISPLAY #     PROCESS ID
:1              26788
PS C:\Users\user>
```

**However with output redirection in to a variable:**

> `PS C:\Users\user> $myoutput=invoke-expression "$mycmd"`
>
> ...still waiting in this state ==> I type my passwd blindly (passwd prompt is captured in $myoutput)
>
> PS C:\Users\user> $myoutput
>
> *user@server's password:*
>
> TigerVNC server sessions:
>
> X DISPLAY #     PROCESS ID
>
> PS C:\Users\server>

$myoutput variable contents is OK But the password prompt is redirected in to the variable too !

**My pbm now is how to make usage comprehensive :user can't guess when typing his passwd :(**
(i.e. how to handle the password prompt?)

**Remarqs**: verbose mode of plink (plink -v ...) still outputting to the console when redirecting to $myoutput

> $myoutput=invoke-expression "$mycmd"

```
Looking up host "server"
Connecting to xxx.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.66
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 blabklablablablabla
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Using username "user".
Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
Attempting GSSAPI authentication
GSSAPI authentication initialisation failed
The target was not recognized.
```

I enter my passwd here (in the dark)

```
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Started a shell/command
Server sent command exit status 1
Disconnected: All channels closed
```

Comment: (1) First of all, you should be aware that the password prompt is part of the output from `plink`.  Are you prepared to handle the first line of `$myoutput` being the password prompt? (2) Since the password prompt is part of the output from `plink`, you should expect it to go into `$myoutput` ***and not to the console.***  When you type `$myoutput=invoke-expression "$mycmd"`, do you get another PS prompt, or does it just seem to hang?  If it just seems to hang, *it may be silently reading the password from the keyboard!* Try typing the password. (Warning: it may display on the console screen.)

Comment: I have rewritten my guidance as an answer.

Comment: Thanks G-Man, nice hint!

Indeed, it's not hanging, it's waiting :)

`PS C:\Users\user> $myoutput=invoke-expression "$mycmd"`

.....still waiting in this state ==> I type  passwd blindly (prompt passwd captured into $myoutput)

`PS C:\Users\user> $myoutput
_user@server's password:_
TigerVNC server sessions:
X DISPLAY #     PROCESS ID
PS C:\Users\server`

$myoutput contents is OK

But my pbm now is how to make usage more freindly: user cant't guess when typing his passwd :(

Remarqs: verbose mode of plink (plink -v) still outputting to the console when redirecting to $myoutput

Answer (score 0):

The password prompt is part of the output from `plink`,
so you should expect it to go into `$myoutput` ***and not to the console.*** 
I expect that, when you type `$myoutput=invoke-expression "$mycmd"`,
it just seems to hang, and doesn’t give you another PS prompt. 
It is probably *silently reading the password from the keyboard!* 
If you just go ahead and type the password, it will work. 
(Warning: the password may display on the console screen.)

As mentioned above,
since the password prompt is part of the output from `plink`,
it goes into `$myoutput`. 
So, you need to be prepared to handle
the first line of `$myoutput` being the password prompt.

Comment: Exact, that's the question now: how to handle this first line of $myoutput to diplay the password prompt ...
Thanks very much G-man, you make my question progressing